# print a previous line based on a condition in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print -4th line based on a condition. I have a text file `SFU.txt` with some content. My objective is: if there is a word `configuration` in a line, I want to print -4th line. For example if the content of my file is like below:

```
This is a random text document
We are talking about planets here
This is planet Mars
in solarsystem
sun is the star
this is 4th planet
configuration lifeform exists
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

So, once the compiler hits the line `configuration lifeform exists` and it sees `configuration`, I want to print the line `This is planet earth`

My code below:

```
file = open("SFU.txt","r")
for line in file:
    if "configuration" in line:
        #want to print the -4th line-HOW?
```

Comment: You mean `This is planet Mars` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tee` to run a pair of iterators across `inf`. This only stores five lines in memory at any given time:

```
from itertools import tee

with open("SFU.txt") as inf:
    # set up iterators
    cfg,res = tee(inf)
    # advance cfg by four lines
    for i in range(4):
        next(cfg)

    for c,r in zip(cfg, res):
        if "configuration" in c:
            print(r)
```

and, as expected, results in

```
This is planet Mars
```

**Edit:** if you want to *edit* the -4th line, I suggest

```
def edited(r):
    # make your changes to r
    return new_r

with open("SFU.txt") as inf, open("edited.txt", "w") as outf:
    # set up iterators
    cfg, res = tee(inf)
    for i in range(4):
        next(cfg)

    # iterate through in tandem
    for c, r in zip(cfg, res):
        if "configuration" in c:
            r = edited(r)
        outf.write(r)

    # reached end - write out remaining queued values
    for r in res:
        outf.write(r)
```

Comment: nice , this is what i was looking for !

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell I want to edit -4th lines, so I should read the whole file into memory to edit it, right?

Comment: amazing how the answer that does everything the OP wants has less votes than others

Answer (score 5):

A limited-size `deque` is a good way to keep a "ring buffer" of the last few lines:

```
import collections

lastfewlines = collections.deque((), 4)

with open('SFU.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'configuration' in line and len(lastfewlines) == 4:
            print(lastfewlines[0])
        lastfewlines.append(line.rstrip())
```

However, while this solves the problem posed in the question, it **doesn't** work for the "real problem" the OP mentioned only in a comment -- "editing" that line, meaning, presumably, alter the input file "in place".

Alas, modern file-systems do **not** allow "in-place editing" of files except byte-for-byte overwriting -- unless the "edited" line is exactly the same number of bytes as the original one, you can't just overwrite said original line and imagine that all the following lines in the file will shift back or forth as desired!-)

Rather, one has to read the file, alter it, and **rewrite** it (the soundest approach is usually to write a new file then rename it to the old one's name "as atomically as your operating system and file-system will let you", to avoid losing data should there be a crash).

The `deque` approach can be adapted to this -- instead of just conditionally printing `lastfewlines[0]`, write to the output file either the original or modified version of it (and at the end write what's left in the `deque` to the output file).  Then, at least on Unix systems and local file-systems, a simple `os.rename` will do the atomic trick (as long as the output file is on the same mounted disk as the input one).

For all but really huge files, however, reading all lines in memory (with `f.readlines()`), performing alterations if any on the list of lines, then writing the lot out again, is much simpler.  And since the user mentions 16,000 lines (length not specified but let's assume less than 100 bytes per average line), this tiny file of less than 2 megabytes should be dealt with in the most simple way -- it's orders of magnitude smaller than any file that would cause any "too big to fit in memory" worries!-)

Comment: Thanks for nice explain and recommending the `deque` its actually desire for this problem , !

Answer (score 3):

If you have a few lines you can use `readlines()` to save your lines as a list then just use indexing :

```
my_file = open("SFU.txt","r").readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(my_file):
    if "configuration" in line:
        print file[i-4]
```

But note that if `i<4` it chose your line from end !

Comment: you might want to make sure i >= 4

Comment: @Kasra eventually I want to edit -4th line. Can I do that by your method? (ofcourse I have to change 'r' to 'r+' or something). My file actually has 16000 lines with about 110 lines with "configuration" in it

Comment: @user5402 mmm if `i<4` it chose from end !

Comment: @SrinGupta using readlines coudn't be an efficient way for files with huge lines ! but with this you can edit your line simply !

Comment: @Kasra what is the best way to deal with this in my case of 16000 lines and 110 occurrences?

Comment: @SrinGupta im thinking on it :) ... maybe using `zip` or `itertools` ! i will edit the answer !

Comment: @Kasra the code doesn't crash but is that the behavior that the OP wants?

Comment: @user5402 i mentioned it on answer ! but i think that `configuration` exist in 4th line to next!

Comment: @SrinGupta check out Hugh Bothwell's answer !

Comment: @SrinGupta, 16,000 lines (presumably of less than, say, 100 bytes each on average) is **tiny** -- there should be absolutely no worry keeping the whole text in memory, it's less than 2 megabytes!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a longer file and don't want to read the whole thing into memory, you can use an efficient queue implementation such as `collections.deque` like:

```python
import collections

myfile = open("SFU.txt","r")

# This is a fixed length queue, and will hold 4 items at most
lines = collections.deque(['']*4,4)

for i, line in enumerate(myfile):
    if 'configuration' in line:
        print lines[0]
    else:
        # push the new line clearing the 4th previous
        lines.append(line)
```

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham. I just removed the "break" statement, and it should work fine for more occurrences. Please note that the asker hadn't mentioned more occurrences, at the time I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this.

As the whole thing is copied to a list, all the text is editable. You can write it back to a file when you are done.

```
f = open("SFU.txt","r")

lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "configuration" in line:
        if i > 4:
            print lines[i - 4]
            # edit here
        else:
            print 'There is no -4th line'

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may open the file twice and yield one file to read from 4th line, then compare the next line first, and print the current line, something like this:

```
with open('SFU.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('SFU.txt', 'r') as next_f:
        [next(next_f) for _ in range(4)] # yield to 4th line first
        for line in next_f:
            if 'configuration' in line: # if keyword in next line
                print next(f) # this is current line from f
                break
            next(f) # if not found, yield f to next line
```

Yield result:

```
This is planet Mars
```

**As a side note**: please try not to use `file` as the namespace as it's a shadow name of Python builtin.