# python - previously defined variable is no longer defined following the use of a tee function

Tags: python

pardon the noob question but fresh out of the classroom here!

i need to extract a string from the previous line when the characters "VOUCHER" is found.

sample data:

> "SUSHI $1 DISCOUNT                  1  $1.00"
> "       VOUCHER #:47412                                                 "

i used the following code to extract the string:

```
voucher,type = tee(rf)
        for i in range(1):
            next(voucher)
            for v,t in zip(voucher,type):
                if '"       VOUCHER #:' in v:
                    type = t.split()
                    type2 = (type[0:len(type)-2])
```

while the code above allows me to extract the "SUSHI $1 DISCOUNT", the previously defined variables are no longer defined... code is structured as follows:

```
from itertools import tee

with open("e-journal.txt","r") as rf:
    with open("e-journal_py output.txt","w") as wf:

        for line in rf:
            line = line.strip()

            if line.startswith("XX"):
                variable "A" defined here

            if line.startswith("XX"):
                variable "B" defined here

            voucher,type = tee(rf)
            for i in range(1):
                next(voucher)
                for v,t in zip(voucher,type):
                    if '"       VOUCHER #:' in v:
                        type = t.split()
                        type2 = (type[0:len(type)-2])
                        print(type2,variable "A",variable "B")
```

do I need to make the previously defined variables nonlocal or global?  is there a better way to extract the "SUSHI $1 DISCOUNT" rather than using the tee function? a shove in the right direciton would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `rf`? Please create a *complete* example. Also, what is the intended purpose of `for i in range(1)`?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel intent of `range(1)` is to refer to the -1 line based on a condition of '"       VOUCHER #:' being met...  found this solution from link below... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079097/print-a-previous-line-based-on-a-condition-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting type when you split it, but maybe you don't want to do that.  Use a different variable name so that you leave type alone.  You could overwrite t instead, for example.

```
t = t.split()
type2 = (t[0:len(t)-2])
```